# How to set up a view containing a list of events ordered by date

Tags: views, 8

I want to have a list of Events on the front-end like this:

```
Upcoming (Newest on top)
<Event1 title> @ <Event 1 Date>
<Event2 title> @ <Event 2 Date>
.
.
Past (in reversed order)
<Event3 title> @ <Event 3 Date>
<Event4 title> @ <Event 4 Date>
```

So I created a `content type`: `event`:

```
Title
Description
Start_Date
```

And a `view`: `events` with the filter criteria `Type = event`.

This gives me a list of all events created. But where to go from here? I created a new views-view--events.html.twig but I don’t know how to retrieve the Start_Date value. Also I think this should/can be done somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view, you may configure the fields you want to show (assuming you want a list of unformatted fields, for easier theming).

You just pick fields as `title` or `date start`/`date end`, so you have them available when the view is processed.

Having them available, the rest is up to you, your project requirements, and twig :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a sort order for past events different to the one you want for future events?

Perhaps you'll have to have to create 2 views and attach one to the other. I think something like that is possible.